# Update a Mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I want to change the value of 2 attributes in all documents where _id is less than 200, the new values will be a random (from 1 to 15). So I started writing this script but doesn't work:

```
    db.myCollection.update(
    { _id: { $lt: 200 }},

   {

     tilte1 : "hello"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16),

     title2 : ["hello"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16),"hello"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16),"hello"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16)], 

   })
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The _id attribute of a document is not an integer. It's an `ObjectId` (12-byte BSON type generated of: timestamp, machine ID, process ID and a process-local incremental counter)

Comment: In my case it's an integer, because I forced that, when creating the collection.

Comment: @SimoSlash You can't use multi documents update without $ operator.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to set those properties to _different_ random values on each doc, you need to update the docs one at a time.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Exactly, else the Math.random will return same value for all documents

Comment: @JohnnyHK and mohamedrias thank you, I will try to use a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.myCollection.update(
    { _id: { $lt: 200 }},
    {
      $set : { title1 : "hello"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16) ,
               title2 : ["hello"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16),"hello"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16),"hello"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16)]}

    }, {multi: true});
```

You need to add `{multi: true}` to update all documents, else it will update only the first document.

And you have typo in the `title1` field. make sure its `tilte1` or `title1`.

In case you want to preserve the previous fields present in the document, use `$set`. As per your current query, it will replace the documents and with just those two fields.

Keep in mind: `Multi updates only works with $ operators`

Comment: Awesome, it works, thank you very much. I have a little problem related to the random, I got the same values in all documents:  "title1" : "hello12" and "title2" : [
  "hello6",
  "hello3",
  "hello15"
 ],

Comment: you need to update the documents one at a time using a loop. Else the math.random will provide same value always.